# google-maps-react not showing boundaries on search

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, geofencing, google-maps-react

[image]

I am working on Google Maps in reactJs and using google-maps-react dependency. I want to achieve results like google map (when I search Lahore on Google Maps, it shows me a boundary of Lahore). How can I do this in my project?

Comment: Where we search on google maps, it appear with Marker and red font already! Do you want to updsate that styling ?